# MFC: Content menu of a second modal dialog not showing

Tags: menu, mfc, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog with a list control. Right clicking one of the items in the list control, shows a content menu. Clicking this popup menu, opens another modal dialog with another list control.

My problem is that I can't display a right click content menu for the list control in the second dialog.

I tried:

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnContextMenu(CWnd* , CPoint point)
{
    if (GetSelectedCount() == 0)
        return ;

    if (point.x == -1 && point.y == -1)
    {
        //keystroke invocation
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(rect);
        ClientToScreen(rect);

        point = rect.TopLeft();
        point.Offset(5, 5);
    }

    CMenu menu;
    VERIFY(menu.LoadMenu(IDR_HISTORY_MENU));

    CMenu* pPopup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
    ASSERT(pPopup != NULL);
    CWnd* pWndPopupOwner = this->GetParent();

    SetForegroundWindow();

    pPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, 
        point.x, 
        point.y,
        pWndPopupOwner); 

}
```

and I also added to the parent dialog ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP

Also tried just to create a popup menu on the fly

```
void CHistoryListCtrl::OnContextMenu(CWnd* , CPoint point)
{
    if (GetSelectedCount() == 0)
        return ;

    if (point.x == -1 && point.y == -1)
    {
        //keystroke invocation
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(rect);
        ClientToScreen(rect);

        point = rect.TopLeft();
        point.Offset(5, 5);
    }

    CMenu addMenu;
    addMenu.CreatePopupMenu();

    // add all possible interface items
    CString mstr; mstr="Compare";
    addMenu.AppendMenu(MF_ENABLED | MF_STRING,ID_HISTORY_COMPARE , (LPCTSTR)mstr);


    addMenu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON,point.x,point.y,this,NULL);


    addMenu.DestroyMenu();
}
```

It didn't work as well. Tried to add SetForgroundWindow before the call to TrackPopupMenu, but it also failed.

Any idea what to do ?

Comment: Do you mean that the popup menu does not display at all, or just that selecting an item in the popup menu doesn't do anything? What value does the call to `TrackPopupMenu()` return?

Comment: I think you need to insert this line: `theApp.OnIdle(-1);` before you call TrackPopupMenu()

Comment: Let me clarify, the popup menu works perfectly fine when it is invoked as a first Modal Dialog. When another modal dialog, invokes this dialog, the popup menu of the list control doesn't work